# Source Code audit

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, ubuntu

I have a question regarding source code review of Linux packages.

I downloaded a package of Ubuntu lets say `samba`, I thought to review source code of `samba` to look for security vulnerabilities.

I used `flaw finder` for code review of `samba` package.

`Flaw finder` generated a report with many vulnerabilities.

For instance there was a vulnerability regarding `strcpy` that says use `strlcpy` or `strncpy` instead of `strcpy` as shown below.

```
httpd-2.4.25/modules/aaa/mod_authn_socache.c:276:9: [4] 
  (buffer) strcpy: Does not check for buffer overflows when copying to destination. 
   Consider using strncpy or strlcpy (warning, strncpy is easily misused).

strcpy(new_context, r->server->server_hostname);
```

1. The point here is that whether `strcpy` function is insecure or not?? If it is insecure then why public community of Ubuntu has not fixed this weakness yet int their latest packages which is so easy to track with open source tool?
2. If we want to secure this `strcpy` function or the code of `samba` itself what are the options?
3. Sorry everyone, mistakenly i copied the apache code and mentioned samba.
4. There is one more point about this. I have downloaded samba and apache latest packages from Ubuntu,s website and then i used flaw finder. Kindly i need your suggestions regarding this. If Ubuntu community has not yet fixed these security weaknesses in their latest packages then should i bother about these security weaknesses or not??

Comment: The key with performing a security review is looking at the output with knowledge of what the code should do. Taking an individual line of code rarely helps - in this case, for example, it's possible that there is no need to check for overflows because the value being copied is of a known length enforced previously. It might be a problem, but there may already be mitigation in place.

Comment: If i want to review and also fix security weaknesses of all the Ubuntu packages. What is the way out??

Answer (score 7):

> For instance there was a vulnerability regarding strcpy...

flawfinder does not report vulnerabilities. To cite from [the description of the program](https://www.dwheeler.com/flawfinder/):

> ... examines C/C++ source code and reports **possible** security weaknesses (“flaws”) sorted by risk level.

Thus, flawfinder does not find vulnerabilities but only shows parts of the program which look like they might be a problem. This includes the use of functions which are often used in the wrong way. To interpret the output, determine the actual risk and fix potential problems a deeper understanding of the analyzed program is required.

To get to your specific questions:

> For that i used flaw finder for code review of samba package.
>   ...
>   httpd-2.4.25/modules/aaa/mod_authn_socache.c:276:9: [4] (buffer) strcpy

It looks like you've analyzed the Apache web server and not samba.

> The point here is that whether strcpy function is insecure or not??

When [looking at the actual context](https://github.com/omnigroup/Apache/blob/master/httpd/modules/aaa/mod_authn_socache.c#L244) you will see with enough understanding of programming that it allocates enough memory directly in the line before this strcpy, i.e. this is not really a problem.

> And if we want to secure this strcpy function or the code of samba itself what are the options??

The options are to

- Use the correct source code in the first place. If you want to audit samba take the source code for samba and not Apache httpd.
- Get a deeper understanding of what the code is doing.
- Determine what the risk of the problem actually is.
- If it really is a problem check if this is already fixed upstream and only not fixed in the distribution version you use.
- Fix the problem [without introducing new bugs](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/05/random_number_b.html) and ship a fix to the developers.

Comment: I humbly apologize. That was a mistake that i mentioned samba and copied apache weakness. Basically i had both the packages so mistakenly done.

Comment: Secondly, if i conclude your point of view then we need manual expertise of source code auditing to patch these security weaknesses.

Comment: @infosec: This is the correct conclusion. flawfinder and other tools do more or less good jobs of showing you some parts where you should take a closer look. The false positive rate is usually very high and they will also find only a part of potential problems. It might help to read [how flawfinder actually works](https://www.dwheeler.com/flawfinder/#how_work) in order to understand what it can provide and what not.

Answer (score 1):

Their is a possibility of a buffer overflow when using the strcpy function. However this will only occur if used incorrectly. Every call to this function needs to be considered in its own context. The tool you are using cannot discern this context so will just give you the generic warning for insecure function use.

This particular example may be using a previous sanitised 'server_hostname' and can guarantee there will be no buffer overflow.

If you really want to change this consider implementing its suggestions, be careful though as the API for strcpy and strlcpy are different. See this article for detailed spec: https://www.sudo.ws/todd/papers/strlcpy.html

Only use the source inspection tool as a guide. Treat it like a automative diagnostic, i.e The tool only points you in the general direction of a potential fault, you need to do the leg work and further diagnostics yourself to fully understand the issue.

Comment: If you have come across IBM appscan source then can you please tell me the strengths of IBM appscan source (tool for source code auditing) as compare to open source tools like flaw finder.